# Trying to use Geocoder for several arrays of 100 addresses each one

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

I use a javascript program that run Geocoder to get latitude and longitude for an array of addresses up to 100 and it run fine. However, if I want to process a list of addresses more than 100, I have to run this program several times, each time filling that array with 100 addresses or less, until I complete my list.

I try to modify it, and split the array in several arrays, each one of 100 addresses and run Geocoder for each array. However, I only get executed the last array, maybe because the program run Geocoder in recursive mode.

Is there a way to run geocode() for several arrays?

In this example, I try to process a array of 150 addresses, so I will split it in two arrays, one of 100 and the other one of 50.

Here I initialize variables:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var map = null;
var geocoder = null;
var addresses = null; /* array that will be used by geocode() function */
var current_address = 0;
var geocode_results = new Array();
var markers = new Array();
var infowindows = new Array();
var timeouts = 0;
var geocodeWait = 1000; //wait a second betweeen requests


function initialize()
{
    var mapOptions = {
        'zoom': 1,
        'center': new google.maps.LatLng(0.0,0.0),
        'mapTypeId': google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);

    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

}
```

This is the function that split array of addresses in 02 arrays and call geocode() function but it only processes last array

```
    function submitForm()
    {
            current_address = 0;

            /* this is the array that will contain list of 150 addressess */
            var temp_addresses = document.getElementById("addresses").value.split("\n");

            for(var x=0;x<2;x++)  /*Here I try to split list in 2 arrays */
            {

                current_address = 0;

                var ini = x*100;

                var fin = ini+99;

                addresses = new Array(); /*array is reinitialized in each loop */

                if  (fin > temp_addresses.length) fin = temp_addresses.length;

                for(var i=ini;i<fin;i++)
                {
                    if(temp_addresses[i].length>1)addresses.push(temp_addresses[i]);
                   /* here 'addresses' array is filled to be used by 'geocode()' function */
                }

                geocode();  /* function is recursive but is only executed when 'x' get last value */
            }
    }
```

Here is the geocode() function:

```
function geocode() {
    if (current_address<addresses.length && geocoder) {
      document.getElementById("progress").innerHTML = "Geocoding " + (current_address+1) + " of " + addresses.length;
      geocoder.geocode( { 'address': addresses[current_address]},
      function(response, status) {
          geocode_results[current_address] = new Array();
          geocode_results[current_address]['status'] = status;
          if (!response || status != google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            if(status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.ZERO_RESULTS){
                geocode_results[current_address]['lat'] = 0;
                geocode_results[current_address]['lng'] = 0;
                current_address++;
            } else {
              timeouts++;
              if(timeouts>6){
                alert("You have reached the limit of of requests that you can make to google from this IP address in one day, please wait 24 hours to continue");
              }
            }
          } else {
            timeouts = 0;
            var top_location = response[0];
            var lat = Math.round(top_location.geometry.location.lat() * 1000000)/1000000;
            var lng = Math.round(top_location.geometry.location.lng() * 1000000)/1000000;
            geocode_results[current_address]['lat'] = lat;
            geocode_results[current_address]['lng'] = lng;
            geocode_results[current_address]['l_type'] = top_location.geometry.location_type;

            var marker = markers[current_address] = new google.maps.Marker({
                  position: new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lng),
                  map: map,
                  title:"Line " + (current_address+1)
             });

            var infowindow = infowindows[current_address] = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                content: addresses[current_address] + "<br/>Latitude:" + lat + "<br/>Longitude:" + lng
            });

            google.maps.event.addListener(markers[current_address], 'click', function() {
              infowindow.open(map,marker);
            });

            current_address++;
          }
          var wait = geocodeWait+(timeouts * geocodeWait); //if it keeps timeing out increase wait time
          setTimeout("geocode()",wait);
      });
    } else {
      document.getElementById("progress").innerHTML = "finished";
      displayResults();
      document.getElementById("progress").innerHTML = "";
      fitAll();
    }
}

function displayResults()
{
    var response = ""
    for(var i=0;i<addresses.length;i++)
    {
        response += addresses[i] + "\t" + geocode_results[i]['lat'] + "\t" + geocode_results[i]['lng'] + "\n";
    }

    document.getElementById("resultados").value += response + "\n";

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try changing the addresses array to a local variable instead of a global variable.

```
function submitForm()
    {
            current_address = 0;

            /* this is the array that will contain list of 150 addressess */
            var temp_addresses = document.getElementById("addresses").value.split("\n");

            for(var x=0;x<2;x++)  /*Here I try to split list in 2 arrays */
            {

                current_address = 0;

                var ini = x*100;

                var fin = ini+99;

                var addresses = new Array(); /*array is reinitialized in each loop */

                if  (fin > temp_addresses.length) fin = temp_addresses.length;

                for(var i=ini;i<fin;i++)
                {
                    if(temp_addresses[i].length>1)addresses.push(temp_addresses[i]);
                   /* here 'addresses' array is filled to be used by 'geocode()' function */
                }

                geocode(addresses);  /* function is recursive but is only executed when 'x' get last value */
            }
    }
```

And accept is a parameter in geocode method

```
function geocode(address)
```

You will need to remove the following line from the top of the file

```
var addresses = null; /* array that will be used by geocode() function */
```

Why exactly do you need to split the address into an array of only 100 addresses? Using an array of 150 addresses should also work.

Instead of iterating over the temp_addresses you could try sending them directly to the geocode function

```
geocode(temp_addresses);
```